# Arithmetic casting to generic type in F#

Tags: generics, casting, f#

I try to write a function which does a generic casting for arithmetic types, for example a function which receives an argument of type `uint64`, then converts to a type being the same as the type parameter. My idea is:

```
let convert<'T> (x:uint64) = 'T x
```

But this code does not compile, and I stuck here after trying several approaches like:

```
let convert<'T> (x:uint64) = 
  match Unchecked.defaultof<'T> with 
    | :? uint32 -> uint32 x
....
```

So how could I write such a generic arithmetic casting in F#? (I just start learning so my question is maybe stupid, please take it easy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use static member constraints, here's a "short" example:

```
type Explicit =
    static member inline ($) (_:byte , _:Explicit) = byte            
    static member inline ($) (_:sbyte, _:Explicit) = sbyte           
    static member inline ($) (_:int16, _:Explicit) = int16           
    static member inline ($) (_:int32, _:Explicit) = int
    // more overloads

let inline convert value: 'T = 
    (Unchecked.defaultof<'T> $ Unchecked.defaultof<Explicit>) value

// Specialized to uint64
let inline fromUint64 (value: uint64) :'T = convert value

// Usage
let x:int = fromUint64 7UL
```

As said in the comments you can use the function `explicit` from [F#+](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus) which covers all cases when there is an explicit operator. Here's a [sample code](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus/blob/master/FSharpPlus/Samples/Conversions.fsx#L14).

Now if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/73b2e1b4431172371ea803a268ff4007da559af9/FsControl.Core/Converter.fs#L20) of that function which is defined in another project (FsControl) you will find an even more complicated workaround.

You may wonder why, so here's the long answer:

In theory it should be possible to use a [single call](http://theburningmonk.com/2012/08/f-defining-explicit-operator-in-f/) invoking the member `op_Explicit`, but that would only work when that member really exists which is not the case with the native number types.

For those cases the F# compiler uses a feature usually referred to as "simulated members" which is implemented using static optimizations but that's not available outside the F# compiler source code.

So F#+ uses a different feature instead: overload resolution, as in the sample code I showed you but it uses an additional overload as a general case for those members which really contain an `op_Explicit` static member.

Comment: Many thanks @Gustavo, this solution is much more superior than my naive approach. An irrelevant remark, you have used the syntax `fun x -> int x` in [`FsControl`](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/master/FsControl.Core/Converter.fs#L22-L37), but here you use the more succint syntax `int`, that made me confused at the first time :)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. There I used the lambda syntax for consistency with the few overloads that required two conversions.

Comment: I wonder whether there is any chance to do similar things with `class` (or `record`)? i.e. something likes `type GenericClass (value : 'T) = ...`, then `let cint = new GenericClass('s')` and `let cstr = new GenericClass("abc")` create two objects of different classes.

Comment: It looks like that's just a normal class with a generic argument in the constructor, I don't think there is anything special there. Unless I'm missing something. Otherwise can you give a better example? May be post it as another question, with all the details.

Comment: Don't even bother that @Gustavo, it was really a stupid question.

Answer (score 5):

`:?` type checks only allow (at least that is my understanding) testing for subtypes of the type of the expression that you match on. As `'T` can be any type, the compiler can't tell if `uint32` is a subtype of that, so that type test is not possible.

To check for "arbitrary" types in match expressions, you need to `box` the value first, essentially cast it to `obj`. As all other types are subtypes of `obj` (`Object` in C# and the CLR at large), you can then test for whatever types you want.

As you noticed correctly, that alone is not enough, because all branches of the match expression need to return the same type. Because the only common supertype of all number types (that I know of) is again `obj`, you need to box each conversion again, and then downcast the result of the match to `'T`. In theory, that is not 100% type safe, but in this case you *know* that the conversion will hold.

```
let convert<'T> (x:uint64) = 
  match box Unchecked.defaultof<'T> with 
    | :? uint32 -> uint32 x |> box
    | :? int -> int x |> box
    :?> 'T
```

Oh, and it probably wouldn't be a good idea to use something like this in performance critical real world code (tight loops etc., large numbers of calls), because number types are value types allocated on the stack, while each boxing of a number allocates an object on the heap that will have to be garbage collected (iirc, boxing a 4-byte integer creates a 16-byte object, so the difference is quite substantial).

Comment: Many thanks for your response, but IMHO this approach does not work, since the return type of the function should be also generic. For example, if we add another matching likes `|:? int16 -> int16 x`, then the compiler will complains because the conflict of return type.

Comment: The downcasting approach does work, many thanks for your answer. Your notice is also very interesting for me.

Comment: Thanks again @TeaDrivenDev, as you said, the performance of this approach is bad. I do not know whether there is a better approach in `F#` (it is quite simple to write such a function using template of `C++` without any problem of performance, but I prefer the type system of `F#`).

Comment: @tathanhdinh A way to speed it up is to use static member constraints. The function `explicit` defined in FSharpPlus does exactly what you want but it checks the type at compile-time. [Here's an example](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus/blob/master/FSharpPlus/Samples/Conversions.fsx).

Comment: @Gustavo I thought there should probably a way like that, but I don't understand static member constraints well enough that I would have been able to tell.

Comment: Yes, it's not straight forward, but basically the type tests are replaced with overload resolution. In [my blog](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/11/07/functions-for-n-tuples/) I wrote how to go from dynamic to static. Hope it helps understanding it.

Comment: Many thanks @Gustavo; using your great `FSharpPlus` is not easy. I have tried with: `let convert<'T> (x:uint64) : 'T = FSharpPlus.Operators.explicit x` but it doesn't work yet. The compiler complains that the type parameter cannot be solved at compile time (which is obviously true). am I wrong at something?

Comment: @Gustavo: correct me if I am wrong, the function `explicit` is _polymorphic_ but not _generic_?

Comment: @TaThanhDinh It is generic, so if you want to create another generic function that does the same (as in the code you are showing) you will need to make it `inline`. And don't use the explicit generic parameter, let the compiler infer it for you.

Comment: @Gustavo I think your approach is much better than my initial idea. I should reconsider the idea of `static member`, I do not know how to use it yet.

Comment: @TaThanhDinh Since you will reconsider this approach I added it as an answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not claiming this is a good idea, but if you want to take @TeaDrivenDev 's idea one step further you can get around the return type limitation using the generic `unbox<'T>` method.

The performance overhead on all of this might be significant of course...

Example code:

```
let convert<'T> (x:uint64) : 'T =
  match box Unchecked.defaultof<'T> with
  | :? uint32 -> uint32 x |> unbox<'T>
  | :? uint16 -> uint16 x |> unbox<'T>
  | :? string -> string x |> unbox<'T>
  | _ -> failwith "I give up"


1u + (12 |> uint64 |> convert) // val it : uint32 = 13u
1us + (uint64 22 |> convert)   // val it : uint16 = 23us
```

This gets around the limitation of all branches having to return the same type, as each branch *does* return the same type for any specific generic parameter. The fact that only one branch will ever return for a specific parameter is neither here nor there to the compiler.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it works perfectly; but I still do not understand why it works. The return type of `uint32 x` must be the primitive type `uint32`,  but why we can `unbox` such a type?, does it work only for `objects`, no?

Comment: Hi @tathanhdinh ! The unbox here doesn't actually do anything here, you're quite right (except add overhead...). The type of ``unbox<'T>`` is ``obj -> 'T`` which means it will take an obj or any subtype of it (i.e. anything) and return 'T. The only reason it is needed here is that the compiler doesn't know that 'T is uint32 on the first branch, uint16 on the second, etc - and using unbox lets it know all branches will return ``'T``.

Comment: Ahh, thanks @mavnn, "...everything is subtype of `obj`" I understand now why it works.